# How to cancel sql query that has been executed without rollback

Tags: sql-server, web-services

I created web service using sql. One of the method is insert into three tables at once. I want to make the error handling.
If the first query executed successfully , and the second fail to execute. 
So, the first query that has been executed will be canceled and the third won't be executed.
If I use rollback, I'm afraid it's going to affect other request, considering I am using web service.
So, is there any way to cancel sql query that has been executed without rollback?

Comment: Wrap your queries in a [transaction](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190612(v=sql.105).aspx).  You can chose to commit or rollback just the queries you specify.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid rolling back is your best option. However, you can create a transaction that envelopes all three insert statements, and check if the transaction succeeds. if it doesn't you can roll back the entire transaction. That is the entire purpose of roll back.

You could capture `SQLException` in your webApi code and delete the content that you added in previous insert statements, but that's a bad idea.